# Finding every nth element in a list

Tags: python

How can I find every nth element of a list?

For a list `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, `returnNth(l,2)` should return `[1,3,5]` and for a list `["dog", "cat", 3, "hamster", True]`, `returnNth(u,2)` should return `['dog', 3, True]`. How can I do this?

Comment: its was introduced in python2.3; see the docs for that--> http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You just need `lst[::n]`.

Example:

```
>>> lst=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> lst[::3]
[1, 4, 7, 10]
>>>
```

Comment: what if we want [2,5,8] ?

Comment: @Cosmic `lst[1::3]`

Answer (score 3):

```
In [119]: def returnNth(lst, n):
   .....:     return lst[::n]
   .....:

In [120]: returnNth([1,2,3,4,5], 2)
Out[120]: [1, 3, 5]

In [121]: returnNth(["dog", "cat", 3, "hamster", True], 2)
Out[121]: ['dog', 3, True]
```

Answer (score -1):

I you need the every nth element....

```
  def returnNth(lst, n):
        # 'list ==> list, return every nth element in lst for n > 0'
        return lst[::n]
```

Comment: -1;               this doesn't add anything new that wasn't already provided by the other two answers, posted 10 minutes' earlier.