# Summing groups of items in a list

Tags: python

```
list1 = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17]
list2 = []
```

I want to add the three first elements to `list2[0]` and the next three to `list2[1]` and so on.

```
1+3+5 is list2[0]
7+9+11 is list2[1]
13+15+17 is list2[2]
```

the result should be:

```
list2 = [9,27,45]
```

Comment: this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680273/finding-every-nth-element-in-a-list

Comment: @smoggers Actually OP wants *add every third element to list2* like `1 + 3 + 5` is `9`, and `7 + 9 + 11` is `27`, etc.

Comment: your question is a good one, but it does not follow the guidelines on how it should be asked. SO is not a code-writing service. Please edit your question and add the code you have tried so far

Comment: @Pynchia: Fair comment; OTOH, the OP _is_ a beginner, and may have been totally baffled as to how to tackle this task. Note that all the answers so far are using module functions and various fancy tricks that a raw beginner wouldn't even know exist. I was almost tempted to write a "raw" answer that just uses simple techniques, but it's _so_ hard to go back to basics once you know the cool stuff. :) The closest I could come was with my code that uses `enumerate()`.

Comment: @PM2Ring I felt for him/her being downvoted heavily. Yes, the solutions are tricky to explain and they need a wider background, in fact I started explaining mine, then I realized it'd be too much anyway. `lvc` has had a go at it, but left out the crucial point about grouping for the same reason

Comment: @PM2Ring I didn't even know there was one!

Comment: There are _lots_ of [SO Chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms?tab=all), but of course the Python one is the best. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for the standard [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module has this recipe for dividing a list into fixed-length groups:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

As a beginner, you might not understand how this works, but I did this to confirm that it does:

```
import itertools as it

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return it.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

list1 = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17]
print(list(grouper(list1, 3)))
```

prints: `[(1, 3, 5), (7, 9, 11), (13, 15, 17)]`. So you have tuples of each three items, now you just need to add them up, which is what the builtin `sum` is for:

```
list2 = [sum(group) for group in grouper(list1, 3)]
```

If your list is a length that isn't divisible by 3, this will break with an error like this:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Which can be fixed in one of two ways: if you want to ignore the odd elements, change `grouper` to call `zip` where it currently calls `it.zip_longest`; on the other hand, if you want a final element in `list2` that is the sum of the odd elements, use a fill value of 0 like this:

```
list2 = [sum(group) for group in grouper(list1, 3, 0)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with

```
gr = [iter(list1)]*3
list2 = [sum(el) for el in zip(*gr)]
# or as an alternative
# list2 = list(map(sum, zip(*gr)))
print(list2)
```

which produces

```
[9, 27, 45]
```

That works if the number of elements in the input list is a multiple of 3.

In case you want to make it work for other lengths as well do

```
from itertools import zip_longest
list1 = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17, 1,2]
gr=[iter(list1)]*3
list2 = [sum(el) for el in zip_longest(*gr, fillvalue=0)]
# or as an alternative
# list2 = list(map(sum, zip_longest(*gr, fillvalue=0)))

print(list2)
```

which produces

```
[9, 27, 45, 3]
```

**EDIT**: another solution is to use `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
g = groupby(enumerate(list1), lambda p, _: p//3)
list2 = [sum(v for p,v in t) for i, t in g]
print(list2)
```

which works for lists of any length (multiple of three or not)

Comment: In case, please accept @Ivc's answer (upvoted). He beat me to it by a few mins. :)

Comment: people are mean on this website, never coming back!

but thanks for the great answer tho :))

Comment: PLEASE, accept lvc's anser instead. It would be fair. Otherwise I am going to delete my answer. PLEASE.

Comment: Thank you. After all, I think lvc did not downvote you and he responded before I did, with a good explanation as well. I had not realized when I was writing mine. BTW, dwell some more on Stackoverflow, do not fear. Just follow the guidelines. If you look at my profile, you will see how badly I started out...

Comment: @J.Cole: You can read about accepting answers, and why it's important, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @PM2Ring I have added another solution, based on `it.groupby` and `enumerate`, which is the first one I thought of this morning, but the rush made me go for the iter grouper instead since it was a bit intricate to extract the elements form the tuples.

Comment: Very cute. FWIW, it's a common convention to use `_` as the name for a `for` loop index that you don't access. Here's a minor variation on your latest solution. `g = groupby(enumerate(list1), lambda (x, _): x//3)` `list2 = [sum(zip(*t)[1]) for _, t in g]`

Comment: @J.Cole: I'm sorry that you feel people are mean on SO. You (probably) got some downvotes on your question because you didn't include any code: you'll get a much better response here if you show us what you've attempted so far, as mentioned in [ask].

Comment: @PM2Ring I am as dumb as a rock sometimes... thank you, edited :D

Comment: There was nothing wrong with your old code, I just thought you might like to see my variation on it. But your new code doesn't work properly (at least, on Python 2.6.6), You _need_ the parentheses so that the lambda has a single (tuple) argument. `groupby(enumerate(list1), lambda (p, _): p//3)`

Comment: @PM2Ring I could update the second line as well,  but I'd end up with two `_` in the comprehension. I think it would work,  but I can't try it right now

Comment: Doing `[sum(v for _,v in t) for _, t in g]` is actually safe, but it's probably less confusing not to do it. But if you want to discuss this stuff further, let's do it in [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of other ways. Note that (as in most of the answers already submitted) a partial group of less than 3 items will be ignored by my first 2 methods, but the last one will handle such partial groups.

```
list1 = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17, 30, 40]
print list1

list2 = [sum(t) for t in zip(*[iter(list1)]*3)]
print list2

list2 = [i + j + k for i,j,k in zip(list1[0::3], list1[1::3], list1[2::3])]
print list2

list2 = []
s = 0
for i, v in enumerate(list1, 1):
    s += v
    if i % 3 == 0:
        list2.append(s)
        s = 0
if s:
    list2.append(s)    
print list2
```

**output**

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 30, 40]
[9, 27, 45]
[9, 27, 45]
[9, 27, 45, 70]
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add the elements from 3*i to 3*(i+1)
where i is will be the index of the new list2

```
>>> list1 = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17]
>>> list2=[]
>>> for i in range(len(list1)/3):
    ...     list2.append(sum(list1[i*3:(i+1)*3]))
>>> list2
[9, 27, 45]
```

Comment: That works ok if the list length is divisible by 3, but you should use `//3` to guarantee integer division. Also, it's (in general) more efficient to use a step of 3 in the `range` (as in  LetzerWille's variation) rather than using those multiplications and divisions by 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17]
# split list1 into 3 sublists
list2 = [list1[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(list1), 3)]
# map sum to sublists in list2
list2 = list(map(sum,list2))
print(list2)
[9, 27, 45]
```